# Unexpected time result for optimization of Project euler Problem 12

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, math, optimization

I have solved [Project Euler problem 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12) and I tried to optimize my solution.
The part I am focusing on is the part of finding the number of divisors.
The first algorithm I created I thought was going to be slower than the second but it wasn't and I don't understand why?

First(regular count goes until n**0.5):

```py
from math import sqrt
def get(n):
    count = 0
    limit = sqrt(n)
    for i in range(1,int(limit)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            count+=2
    if limit.is_integer():
        return count-1
    return count
```

Second(Prime factoring to get each the degree of each prime in order to use this [fomula](https://mathschallenge.net/library/number/number_of_divisors), I am using the form of primes [as you can see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41623/is-that-true-that-all-the-prime-numbers-are-of-the-form-6m-pm-1) to calculate faster but its is still slower ).:

```py
def Get_Devisors_Amount(n):#Prime factorization
    if n <=1: return 1
    dcount = 1
    count = 0
    while n%2==0:
        count+=1
        n//=2
    dcount*=(count+1)
    
    count = 0
    while n%3==0:
        count+=1
        n//=3
    dcount*=(count+1)
    
    i = 1#count for the form of primes 6n+-1
    while n!=1:
        t = 6*i+1
        count = 0
        while n%t==0:
            count+=1
            n//=t
        dcount*=(count+1)
        t = 6*i-1
        count = 0
        while n%t==0:
            count+=1
            n//=t
        if count!=0:
            dcount*=(count+1)
        i+=1
        if dcount==1: return 2# n is a prime
    return dcount
```

How I tested the time

```py
import time
start = time.time()
for i in range(1,1000):
    get(i)

print(time.time()-start)


start = time.time()
for i in range(1,1000):
    Get_Devisors_Amount(i)

print(time.time()-start)
```

Output:
get:  0.00299835205078125
Get_Devisors_Amount:  0.009994029998779297

Although I am using property and a formula that I think should make the search time lower the first method is still faster. could you explain why to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first approach, you testing divisibility with each number from 1 to `sqrt(x)`, so the complexity of testing a single number is `sqrt(x)`. According to [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-sum-of-the-square-roots-of-first-n-natural-number) formula, the sum of first `n` roots can be approximated to `n*sqrt(n)`.
**Time complexity of method 1**: `O(N*sqrt(N))` (N is the total count of numbers being tested).

In the second approach, there are 2 cases:

1. If a number isn't prime, all primes upto `n` are tested. Complexity - `O(n/6) = O(n)`
2. If a number is prime, we can approximate the complexity to be `O(log(n))` (there might be a more accurate calculation of the complexity for this case, I'm making an approximation since this wouldn't matter in the proof)

For the prime numbers, using the fact that we test them with `(n/6)` primes, the complexity would become `5/6 + 7/6 + 11/6 + 13/6 + 17/6 ..... (last prime before n)/6`. This can be reduced to `(sum of all prime numbers till n)/6` for the time being. Now, the sum of all prime numbers upto `N` can be [approximated](https://mathoverflow.net/a/63427) as `N^2/(2*logN)`. Thus the complexity for this step becomes `N^2/(6*(2*logN)) = N^2/(12*lognN)`.

**Time complexity of method 2**: `O(N^2/(12*lognN))` (N is the total count of numbers being tested).

(if you want, you can make more accurate bounds for the time complexities of each step. I have made a few approximations since it helps in proving the point without making any overoptimistic assumption).

Comment: thank you for this great and comprehensive answer. (sorry I can't vote it up yet)

Answer (score 0):

Your first algorithm wisely only considers divisors up to sqrt(n).

But your second algorithm considers divisors all the way up to n, although admittedly if n has many factors, n will be reduced along the way.

If you fix this in your algorithm, by changing this:

```
t = 6*i-1
```

to this:

```
t = 6*i-1
if t*t > n:
  return dcount * 2
```

Then your second algorithm will be faster.

(The `* 2` is because the algorithm would eventually find the remaining prime factor (n itself) and then `dcount *= (count + 1)` would double dcount before returning it.)

Comment: thank you for your response. But your fix doesn't work but it gave me the idea to add  ` if n!=1 and OriginalN%n==0: return dcount*2` OriginalN is the variable I added at the beginning as a copy of n